# Is there a substitute to testflight for android

Tags: android, testflight

Since testflight will be revoking upload support for android, is there any other service that provides the same service like testflight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Apphance](http://www.utest.com/apphance) 
or  [TestFairy](https://www.testfairy.com/)

Comment: These looks great. Will try these out.

Comment: I switched to testFairy for now. Good interface and free service. Thanks

Comment: Apphance is no longer available. They were acquired by applause.com

Answer (score 12):

Google play has support for beta (and alpha) testing. Check:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish -> Your App -> APK -> Beta Testing -> Manage list of testers

You have to create a google+ page or a google group. Once your beta testers join your group, you can send them an opt-in link (provided by google play when you set up beta testing)

Then they get the beta apk through google play. No need for testflight.

Answer (score 9):

Google has a mechanism built into Play allowing you to distribute builds to testers. I've used it for a few apps (Facebook, WordPoppr, and Apex Launcher, for example), and I found it a bit quirky but it's definitely a workable option. You should be able to find that in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).

If you liked TestFlight, you might like something that offers more features and control than the Google Play process. If you try Google's method and don't like it, [AppBlade](https://appblade.com/) is a great option. It has crash reporting, in-app feedback, public recruitment links (for social media or email), connects directly to your CI service and GitHub/JIRA/BugZilla/etc, is compatible with Cordova/PhoneGap and even has security built into the Apps to protect and manage those for you - which is really nice when you're working with APKs that can easily leak out otherwise. It's also built to be easier to use for you and more convenient for your testers than the alternative. Check it out, you may like it!

Comment: Im sorry I didnt read this before. But appblade seems promising. Im trying that too now